How to fix buildozer Operation not permitted error
Everytime I activate the command buildozer android debug in /mnt/d/MyWork/PswdMaker_App with wsl, I always face this problem.
error: chmod on /mnt/d/MyWork/PswdMaker_App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted

I tried chmod 777 /mnt/d/MyWork and cmown $USER:$USER /mnt/d/MyWork, it doesn't changed at all...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
